# Regex for Two Digits and a Hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I've got a very long text file as a result of a test last night. Stupidly I forgot to format it correctly with `"\n"`. A sample is:

`"01-someText151645.txt,Wed Feb  1 16:15:18 2012,1328112918.57801-HalfMeg151646.txt,Wed Feb  1 16:15:18 2012,1328112918.578"... on and on.`

As you can see there is no space between the end of the epoch timestamp and the text file name. Fortunately each text file starts with two numbers and a hyphen. So the above sample should look like this:

```
01-someText151645.txt,Wed Feb  1 16:15:18 2012,1328112918.578
01-someText151646.txt,Wed Feb  1 16:15:18 2012,1328112918.578
```

Unfortunately a previous project where I had lots of Regex parsing isn't to hand and thus need a little help getting a regex for this. My plan is to then use a `re.findall(regex, sample)` to get the information I want.

Edit: Just to explicitly say that each line has a text file name, a date and epoch timestamp, all separated by "," (no spaces). Each file begins with 2 digits and a hyphen. So that is: `textfile,date,epoch`, textfile= `digit,digit,-`

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you're using :)

Comment: Updated the post: It's python :)

Comment: is there any consistency among the text file names?

Comment: Just updated with a little more information. Does that help? Regexs are the bane of my life.

Comment: @BarryChapman: Say what? You have POSIX Regex, Perl compatible Regex, Extended Regex, basic Regex, Python's Regexs... Every implementation is a bit different, especially with regards to which character classes they support and what not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I've thrown together, manipulate it to suit:

```
import re

m = """01-someText151645.txt,Wed Feb 1 16:15:18 2012,1328112918.57801-HalfMeg151646.txt,Wed Feb 1 16:15:18 2012,1328112918.578"""

print(m)

addNewLineBefore = lambda matchObject: "\n" + matchObject.group(0)

print ( re.sub(r'\d{2}-',addNewLineBefore,m) )
```

It assumes, that the `\d{2}-` match is unique to the beginning of a line. If there's a possibility they appear within the line, such as in the filename, I can edit this answer to accommodate

**EDIT:** In the event you don't want to read your entire file into memory, you can use a buffer:

```
import re
input = open("infile","r")
output = open("outfile","w")

oneLine = re.compile(r"""(
        \d{2}-  # the beginning of the line
        .+?     # the middle of the line
        \.\d{3} # the dot and three digits at the end
)""", re.X)

while buffer:
    buffer = input.read(6000) # adjust this to suit
    #newbuffer = re.split(r'(\d{2}-.+?\.\d{3})',buffer) # I'll use the commented re object above
    newbuffer = oneLine.split(buffer)
    newbuffer = filter(None,newbuffer)
    output.write( "\n".join(newbuffer) )
input.close()
output.close()
```

This shouldn't be used if error checking and efficiency are necessities. From what I understand, this is a very controlled and informal environment

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you! :D I'll try it on the main file now.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
([0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{5,}[0-9]{5,}\.txt){1,}
```

That would match (closely but loosely) the format of your filename. You can adjust to your needs.

Do a split on this, and then separate the file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is sufficiently small to allow it to be read into memory all at once, then you could simply split it on a lookahead regex

```
re.split('(?=\d\d-)', contents)
```

or to insert newlines where they belong

```
re.sub('(?=\d\d-)', "\n", contents)
```